minimum element in permutation cycles
As a part of a competitive programming problem that I was solving, I had to compute the following.
Let $n$ be some positive integer, and let $[n]$ denote the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Consider the group of permutations $S_n = \{\sigma:[n]\to [n] | \sigma \textrm{ is a bijection }\}$.
Fix some $k\in [n]$. Using the cycle decomposition, we can decompose any permutation into a product of disjoint cycles. Consider the cycle $C$ containing $k$. How many permutations are there such that $k$ is the minimal element of its own cycle $C$?
By a direct counting argument, we can choose some $j$ elements greater than $k$, form the cycle using these $j$ elements along with $k$ in $j!$ ways and arrange the remaining elements in any way, whence the answer is:
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{n - k} \binom{n - k}{j}j!(n - j - 1)!$$
After expanding out the binomial coefficient and using the hockey-stick identity, I obtained the answer: $$\frac{n!}{k}$$
Probabilistically speaking, this means that if we randomly pick a permutation, then
$$\mathbb{P}[k\textrm{ is the minimum in its cycle}] = \frac{1}{k}$$
I was wondering if there is some clean bijective proof of this fact or a probabilistic interpretation of this that does not involve a summation.
Edit: The editorial for the problem provides an alternate, somewhat more illuminating, counting argument.
Visualize the process of building the permutation digraph adding the elements of $[n]$ one at a time, in increasing order.
Observe that for the first $k$ elements, we must have $k$ in a cycle consisting only of itself, otherwise, it is not the minimal element of the cycle. The other elements so far can be arranged in $(k-1)!$ ways.
For each $i > k$, we can do either of the following:

Insert it into one of the pre-existing edges i.e. for $a, b < i$ where currently $a\mapsto b$, we convert it into $a\mapsto i$, $i\mapsto b$.
We can put it into a cycle by itself.

Therefore, there are $i + 1$ choices to extend the permutation.
The total number of permutations that satisfy this is thus,
$$(k-1)!(k+1)(k+2)\ldots n = \frac{n!}{k}$$

There's an even simpler way to state the probabilistic statement using the "building up" intuition. Imagine generating the permutation by adding elements one by one randomly. Specifically, at step $k$, there are $k$ choices for where to put $k$ ($k-1$ choices in existing cycles, plus $1$ for starting a new cycle), and each has probability $1/k$. But $k$ is the minimum of its cycle if and only if it starts a new cycle when it's added, which happens with probability $1/k$.

There is a clean bijective proof.
Consider this bijection from $F:S_n\to S_n$, due to Foata [1].

Given $\pi\in S_n$, find the cycle decomposition of $\pi$.  For example, let $\pi=[3,7,1,9,5,8,4,6,2]$ in one-line notation, meaning $\pi(1)=3,\pi(2)=7,$ etc, then the cycles are $(3\;1)$, $(9\;2\;7\;4)$, $(6\;8)$ and $(5)$.

Rewrite each cycle of $\pi$ so that the smallest element of the cycle comes first. For example, $(9\;2\;7\;4)$ would be written as $(2\;7\;4\;9)$.

Re-order the cycles to be in decreasing order of their smallest element. For our running example, we write $\pi$ like $$(6\;8)(5)(2\;7\;4\;9)(1\;3).$$

Finally, delete all parantheses, leaving a string of $n$ distinct numbers from $1$ to $n$. We then interpret this as a permutation in $S_n$, written in one-line notation. For $\pi$ in the previous bullet point, the result is $$F(\pi)=6\;8\;5\;2\;7\;4\;9\;1\;3.$$ This step does not lose any information; we can recover where the parentheses were, since there is a closing and opening parenthesis before any number which is smaller than all numbers to its left.


Since all of these steps are reversible, this is a bijection from $S_n$ to $S_n$.
Now, consider a uniformly random permutation $\sigma\in S_n$. Let $\pi=F^{-1}(\sigma)$; since $F$ is a bijection, $\pi$ is also a uniformly random permutation in $S_n$. We want to find the probability that $k$ is the smallest element of its cycle in $\pi$. The key point is this:

$k$ is the smallest element of its cycle in $\pi$ if and only if $k$ appears earlier than all of $\{1,2,\dots,k-1\}$ in $\sigma$.

Indeed, looking at $\sigma$, suppose that $k$ does not appear first among $\{1,\dots,k\}$. Then there exists some $j$  such that, when all numbers except for $\{1,\dots,k\}$ are deleted from $\sigma$, then $j$ is immediately before $k$. But in that case, $k$ will be in the same cycle as $j$ in $\pi$, so $k$ is not the smallest of its cycle. Conversely, if $k$ appears the earliest out of all of $\{1,\dots,k\}$in $\sigma$, then $k$ will be less than every number to its left in $\sigma$, which implies that $k$ is the smallest element of its cycle in $\pi$.
Since the probability that $k$ appears the earliest out $\{1,\dots,k\}$ is $1/k$ (any of these $k$ numbers is equally likely to appear earliest), this proves that the probability $k$ is the smallest number of its cycle is $1/k$.

Foata, D. "Rearrangements of words", in Combinatorics on Words, edited by M. Lothaire, Volume 17 of Encyclopedia of Mathematics (Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA), 1983, pp. 184–212. https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511566097

